# Why are these default arguments allowed?

Tags: c++, default-arguments

I've found [this](http://www.mycppquiz.com/question.php?qid=60) question, and I'm completely baffled.

The answer says `b` is invalid, "Non-static members can not be used as default arguments.". That makes perfect sense.

What I don't understand is why the other two are okay. In fact, I'm struggling to understand what the semantics are if the default is not a constant expression...

What's going on here? Default parameters are clearly evaluated at compile time. Does the compiler simply pick the current value?

```
#include <iostream>

int g_x = 44; 

struct Foo 
{ 
  int m_x; 
  static int s_x; 

  Foo(int x) : m_x(x) {} 
  int a(int x = g_x) { return x + 1; } 
  int b(int x = m_x) { return x + 1; }
  int c(int x = s_x) { return x + 1; }
}; 

int Foo::s_x = 22; 

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{ 
  Foo f(6); 

  std::cout << f.a() << std::endl; 
  std::cout << f.b() << std::endl; 
  std::cout << f.c() << std::endl; 

  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: "Default parameters are clearly evaluated at compile time" - no they're not. They're evaluated each time the function is called.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Looks like an answer, smells like an answer...

Comment: I didn't know non-static members can't be used as default parameters. I don't know why that's not allowed.

Comment: @PhilH: It's a fragment of an answer. Now there's a proper answer.

Comment: @NeilKirk: For the same reason that other parameters can't be used (`this` being a special case of a parameter). The evaluation order isn't specified, but would need to be to resolve dependencies between argument evaluations.

Comment: I added some more details to address why it is okay to use static members but not non-static members.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, default arguments are evaluated when the function is called, which is why this is okay. From the [draft C++ standard](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/b7b8ed08ba4c111ad03e13e8524a1b746cb74ec6/papers/N3936.pdf) section `8.3.6` *Default arguments* which says (*emphasis mine going forward*):

> **Default arguments are evaluated each time the function is called**. The order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified.
>   Consequently, parameters of a function shall not be used in a default
>   argument, even if they are not evaluated. Parameters of a function
>   declared before a default argument are in scope and can hide namespace
>   and class member names.

The following example from the same section gives us a rationale for why we can use static members but not non-static ones:

> [ Example: the declaration of X::mem1() in the following example is
>   ill-formed because no object is supplied for the non-static member
>   X::a used as an initializer.
>
> ```
> int b;
> class X {
>     int a;
>     int mem1(int i = a); // error: non-static member a
>                          // used as default argument
>     int mem2(int i = b); // OK; use X::b
>     static int b;
> };
> ```
>
> **The declaration of X::mem2() is meaningful, however, since no object
>   is needed to access the static member X::b.** Classes, objects, and
>   members are described in Clause 9. —end example ]

Comment: I don't see how the example explains why a non-static member cannot be used as a default argument.
What is the potential problem of having your non-static member `a`, such that two objects of the same class `x`, say `x1` and `x2`, each with its own value of `a`, say `x1.a=2` and `x2.a=3`, use it as the default argument for `mem1`, e.g. in `x1.mem1()` and `x2.mem1()`?

Answer (score 7):

Default arguments aren't evaluated at compile time. They're evaluated each time a function call requires them. They can be any expression that's valid in the context of the function declaration and has a suitable type, except that it can't use any other parameters (including `this`, in the case of a member function).

That restriction is because the evaluation order isn't specified, so there's no way to ensure a parameter value is available if it were needed to evaluate another argument.

Comment: Could you provide an example code that shows evaluation order is important, and in that case using a non-static default argument would lead to problems?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is understandable:
g_x and s_x are available at compile time but this (and therefore this->m_x) is not.
You can use a trick to use m_x:

```
int b(int x = -1) { return x == -1 ? m_x + 1 : x + 1; }
```

(Of course -1 should be illegal input in this case.)

Comment: But they're not available at compile time. They're not `const`, so the value could change at run-time, and be different for each function call.

Comment: Mike, you mix two things: the values are unavailable but the objects (the address) are available at compile time. And it's enough to have an address where to get the default value from. Anyway (even if you use a const or a literal) you only have a simple address where the value is.